# How to call Oracle11g UCM custom service into Java code of another custom component?

Tags: java, oracle11g, oracle-ucm

I have two Oracle UCM component UCMComponent1 and UCMComponent2. UCMComponent1 has multiple custom services.So my requirement is that I want to call UCMComponent1 custom service into UCMComponent2 java method.

Anyone has any idea how I can able to call this custom service in Java method? I know how to call UCM existing service into Java method.

Thank you !

Comment: Cross linking to [OTN forum thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3882827).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All services are available the same way regardless of which component they live in. I guess your service definition is missing something (like an access bit?)

Comment: Thanks Sam and Jonathan for your quick reply. Will try to call component service as I am calling UCM existing service.